# Can I use vodka to clean my wine cellar?

Tags: cleaning

I want to use vodka to clean my wine cellar, does it leave lingering odors behind and affect the taste and aroma of my wines.

Comment: Can you help us understand why you want to do this?

Comment: I want to use it to clean the dust as well as prevent mold and milvew.

Comment: `use it to clean the dust` ... have you not heard? ...  someone invented a device called a vacuum cleaner .... you can use it to remove dust

Comment: I cook with wine sometimes even putting some in the food. I clean with beer. I would clean with vodka if I had cranberry juice

Comment: Yes but the  more vodka you drink the less cleaning you will do.

Comment: I find that scrubbing with caviar and then rinsing with 100 year old scotch works best (75 year will work in a pinch though).

Comment: Welcome to Home Improvement! Unfortunately, unorthodox cleaning questions are off-topic. Please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how better to contribute here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because unorthodox cleaning techniques are off-topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've drunk some cheap vodka in my time ($US3 per liter was the cheapest) but I still wouldn't use it for cleaning unless that was the only option I had.  Vodka is not pure alcohol so it will leave varying degrees of residue do to flavonoids etc

If I was going to use an alcohol based product for cleaning I would tend towards a [Rubbing Alcohol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubbing_alcohol) that, while still not 100% pure alcohol, minimizes the amount of other ingredients and carries no perfume oils etc

Comment: Denatured alcohol would be a better bet, because it's significantly cheaper and available in larger quantities at hardware stores.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could use vodka safely but not on the labels, but that is not really needed. A soft dry cloth to clean off the wine bottles will work just fine.

As far as mold and mildew, if you have an issue, you need to remediate that  so the humidity isn’t excessive.

I did find a somewhat interesting post by [Martha Stewart](https://www.themarthablog.com/2018/06/cleaning-the-wine-cellar-at-my-farm.html) on her wine cellar being cleaned.